# Adding global.aspx file

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I am currently using IIS to host a simple website, and would like to know how to enable the 'Global.aspx' file? I need to know where I would define it, as all the tutorials talk about using Visual Studio, which I am not using.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using, and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `Global.asax` should be placed on the root directory of your site. There is nothing else to do besides adding required code, you put it there and just work.

Comment: I have done that, however upon restarting the server, it remains blank. I thought it was meant to auto-populate?

Comment: @Lloyd268: global.asax won't autopolulate, you'll need to add content manually

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on the project name displayed in the Solution Explorer, and choose `Add New...`, then choose `Global.asax` from the list displayed in the new popup window. It goes to the root of your application.

Here is further information: [Where is the Global.asax.cs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288209/where-is-the-global-asax-cs-file)

Comment: As I said, I am not using Visual Studio, and there is no 'Solution Explorer' in IIS 7.5

Comment: @Lloyd268 Having a site's code (even a simple one) purely in IIS is not a good idea. It's harder to develop, it doesn't let you easily have separate production vs testing environments. At the very least, you should have the code reside on a dev machine, do source code control with SVN or Git, and deploy your code when you're sure it's working to your server. Visual Studio will make that a lot easier, and there's several great free options.